# An Infinite set such that all of its subsets are finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is there an infinite set X such that every proper subset of X is finite? Does the existence of X depend on the definition of finiteness used?

EDIT: Despite the actual wording of this question, I was really asking about the existence of amorphous sets.

Comment: Proper Subsets.

Comment: If $x \in X$, and $X$ is infinite, can $X \setminus \{x\}$ be finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such set. If every proper subset of $X$ is finite, then either $X$ is empty (in which case it's finite), or $X\setminus \{a\}$ is finite where $a$ is some chosen element of $X$. But then $X=(X\setminus \{a\})\cup\{a\}$ is a union of two finite sets, hence finite. (And this is just a really tedious way to say "finite plus one = finite," or "you can add one to a natural number and get a natural number.")

---

Now this might feel like cheating, since $X\setminus\{a\}$ is "barely" a proper subset of $X$; and we could ask:

> Can there be a set $X$ such that whenever $Y\subseteq X$ and $X\setminus Y$ is infinite,then $Y$ is finite?

The answer to this is **yes** (assuming we're just working in ZF set theory rather than ZFC) - such sets are called **[amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set)**, and it is consistent with ZF that there are amorphous sets.

Comment: We can even construct a Hilbert's hotel-style bijection between $X$ and $X \setminus \{a\}$, if so inclined.

Comment: @Bungo Not in ZF alone - it is consistent with ZF that there are [infinite Dedekind-finite sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set#Relation_to_the_axiom_of_choice) (even [amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set)!).

Comment: Good point, we need AC to choose a countably infinite subset of $X$ to form our hotel.

Comment: Aha! This is what I was really asking about. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

No. Proof by contradiction:

Suppose you have some infinite set $X$ whose every proper subset is finite.

Then take any $x \in X$, and consider $X-\{ x \}$. This is a proper subset, and hence is finite, and has cardinality $n$ for some number $n$. But that means that $|X|=n+1$, i.e. $X$ is finite. Contradiction!